# How to get value the input type without value attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i got stuck with this. I have HTML file like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.supplier').change(function() {
    var capacityValue = $('select.supplier').find(':selected').data('capacity');
    $('.supplierCapacity').val(capacityValue);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.supplier').change(function() {
    var countryValue = $('select.supplier').find(':selected').data('country');
    $('.supplierCountry').val(countryValue);
  });
});
```

```css
select,
input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Choose Supplier :
<br>
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
  <select class="supplier" name="supplier">
    <option data-country="Argentine" data-capacity="100" value="10">Johny Farms</option>
    <option data-country="Belgium" data-capacity="200" value="20>">Jack & Jane Farms</option>
    <option data-country="Canada" data-capacity="300" value="30">Crabs Crane</option>
  </select><br>

  <input type="hidden" name="supplierCapacity" class="supplierCapacity" readonly /><br>
  Country :<br>
  <input type="text" name="supplierCountry" class="supplierCountry" readonly /><br>
  <input type="submit" value=" save ">
</form>
```

How do get the input value to post. I wrote this code in submit.php but doesn't work:

```
$capacity = $_POST['supplierCapacity'];
$country = $_POST['supplierCountry'];
```

Comment: What you have should work fine, although note that you can join both the DOMReady and `change` event handlers in to one - but that won't affect the outcome of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a id for the input

```
<input id="testing"  />
```

In javascript, to get the input value

```
document.getElementId('testing').value
```

Or

```
$('#testing').val();
```

Comment: You can also do `$("input[name='supplierCapacity']").val();`